# WPF DataGrid: numeric columns with fixed decimals positions

Tags: wpf, vb.net, format, numeric

I'm having issues getting the right visualization for some datas displayed in DataGrid (WPF, not Forms DataGridView).

I'm loading my datatable which contains some numeric columns. Some values have a decimal part, some don't, like 2 , 2.5, 10 and so on.
What I've seen is DataGrid automatically displays decimals positions only if they're necessary, so "5" is displayed just like "5". For readability purpose, I'd like to format all numbers with one decimal position. I tried to use `Format(myNumber, "0.0")`, but this return a string: the problem then is the ordering, which is not executed as expected (this way it's ordered like string, not numbers).

Any ideas? Does someone already faced this?

Comment: Hello , did you find solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this.

The problem is that I have to generate the columns in code. My DataGrid is set with AutoGenerateColumns=True.

Then I added this code:

```
Private Sub DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn(sender As Object, e As DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs) Handles DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn
    If e.PropertyType = GetType(Date) Then
        TryCast(e.Column, DataGridTextColumn).Binding.StringFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
    End If
End Sub
```

In this way, I can easily adjust the date format to user's preferences.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

**XAML:**

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding myNumber, StringFormat=N0}" Header="price"/>
```

`StringFormat=N0` convert *5.00* to *5* and if you want show one position use *N1* to show *5.0* .

**Code-behind :**

`myNumber.ToString("N0");`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try it, but since I need a code-side solution, please can you explain how to do this? I'm quite new to WPF.

Comment: @FrankIsNotNothing I update my answer , you can see what is your need.

Comment: Thank you Nebez, but I think in this way it returns a string, not a double. Then I have the DataGrid ordering issue...

Comment: @FrankIsNotNothing please provide your XAML and Codes in question. also how you said it? did you test codes?